# Cutting off electric in detached garage

Tags: electrical, wiring

My home comes with a detached garage which is leased out by my landlord to someone else. However the electricity supply is connected to my home. Therefore I am paying for it all. How do I disconnect it. There is no trip switch in the meter for it. The cable is hard wired into a socket in my garden. The landlord told me to ask for money from these people. I don't wanna chase strangers for money and monitor the usage.

Comment: Depending on the amount of electricity that that that garage uses(one light or heated by electricity) have the landlord reduce your rent.  probably raise theirs, but not your problem.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "trip switch in the meter". If you have a small panel together with the meter, it is likely that it has one large breaker which controls everything in your house, garden, etc. In which case you should have a *panel* somewhere in your house that has individual breakers for lights, kitchen receptacles, bathroom receptacles, washer, dryer, other receptacles, etc. And if that's the case, try *every* breaker until you find the one that does it.

Comment: The place probably isn't legally rented out.  Most jurisdictions have codes against renting out a single family residence like this (detached building to a separate party).  It will be worth your while to find out if this is the case where you live. The landlord isn't in a position to ask you to ask them for money.  You don't work for the landlord.  Tell them that you're going to deduct 50% of the electric bill from your rent.  If they say something, well, I guess there's a disagreement and it can be worked out by a judge.

Comment: Is the garage rented as garage/storage/workshop? Or is rented as an apartment? If it is rented as an apartment then there are a *lot* of other issues that may come up in terms of minimum legal requirements for plumbing, electrical, ventilation, etc. Landlord probably won't be happy if this ends up in court...

Comment: Most places anyone is allowed to change receptacles (i.e. for repair or color change) in a rental unit without pulling a permit.  So change that receptacle because you'd prefer a white one or a GFCI.  And you happened to see an illegally constructed tap, so you left it off instead of continuing the violation.  Or if it's fed from a socket inside the house, and you need the rest of the circuit, fit a GFCI at that socket, trip it, and don't reset it lol.

Answer (score 3):

Since you can't (legally) do electric work yourself in a rented home in most places, you are likely limited to "turn off a breaker". Find which breaker controls the socket in the garden and turn it off. Then see if it controls anything else that *you* need. If it does, you're stuck. If it doesn't, leave that breaker off and wait for the complaints - and tell them to call the landlord.